# how to convert Object[] to String[ ]

Tags: android, android-listview

in order to list all running applications in a listview, I need to convert an Array of Objects to a Array of Strings.

With this code I read out all running processes:

```
 private String[] runningProcesses() {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List l = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
    Iterator i = l.iterator();
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo) (i.next());
        try {
            c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
            Log.w("LABEL", c.toString());



        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Name Not FOund Exception
        }
    }


    Object[] object = l.toArray();
```

How to convert `object`to a `string[]`in order to list all running processes in a listView?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why not using `l` as data-source for Adapter instead of getting `Object` Array?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot convert a `List<RunningAppProcessInfo>` to a `String[]` directly. Instead, store the labels (that you're logging) into a separate `List` and convert it to an array on return.

```
List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

while (i.hasNext()) {
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo) (i.next());
    try {
        c = pm.getApplicationLabel(pm.getApplicationInfo(info.processName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
        Log.w("LABEL", c.toString());
        labels.add(c.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Name Not FOund Exception
    }
}

// convert to array and return
return labels.toArray(new String[0]);
```